# Is there a way to prevent a stylesheet from loading if JS is enable?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to design a tumblr theme. I am finding that it is very limited on how you can style it.

I am thinking of using this kind of thing to load different stylesheets for different pages:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
if (pathname.indexOf("tagged/inspiration") != true){
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css' /> 
}
```

Now the problem is that if js is disable I dont get that file. As such I thought I'd add a stylesheet like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='no-js/css' />
```

Though is it posible to hide this is js is enabled?

**And most importantly is there anything wrong with what I am trying to do?**

How likely is it for people that would read a web design blog to have javascript disable?

Thanks a lot

Comment: +1 for understanding the problem and describing it well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- HTML is your Model
- CSS is your View
- JS is your Controller

HTML handles the data
CSS handles the styles
JS handles the interactions

If you need styles to apply only to JS, prefix the style with `.js`:

```
#foo { color: red; }

.js #foo { color: blue; } /* javascript enabled style */
```

and call:

```
$('html').addClass('js');
```

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) will handle this for you, as well as adding a large number of other classes useful for feature detection.

---

If you feel that need to add a second stylesheet (one for JS, one for non-JS) there are a number of different ways it can be done. For the following examples, I'm assuming `link[rel="stylesheet"][type="text/css"]`, but I'm too lazy to add them in.

#### Additive with no JS as default:

```
<link href="no-js.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<link href="js.css" />');
</script>
```

#### Additive with JS as default:

```
<link href="js.css" />
<noscript>
  <link href="no-js.css" />
</noscript>
```

#### Replacement

```
<link href="no-js.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('link').last().attr('href', 'js.css');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great description, I have added Modernizr  but I forgot that, thats kind of what it is for (first time of using it). However, the css files are too big and slightly harder to manage so I will go with one of your three examples. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just put your default stylesheet link in a no script tag:

```
<noscript>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='no-js/css' /> 
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply only include the customised CSS file if client-side scripts are disabled / not available on client, i.e.

```
<noscript>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='no-js/css' />
</noscript>
```